# Redirect 301 url with multiple parameters to another url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I find many solutions for similar case, but I can't find any for this one. I have some old urls with parameters to permanently redirect on homepage. There is example:

```
#old url https://www.example.com/?s=141&sid=5 
#new url https://www.example.com
```

I'm trying to do some like this, but I can't find out how to make it works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=141&sid=5
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

This is not working either

```
Redirect 301 /?s=141&sid=5 https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=141&sid=5$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com? [R=301,L]
```

or if not working above

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([\d+])&sid=([\d+])$
RewriteCond %1 ^141$
RewriteCond %2 ^5$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. First one is working. Now I see my mistake.